# Loading Java-based R packages (e.g. XLConnect) using RCaller

Tags: java, r, rcaller

I am calling R Scripts from Java using [`R Caller 2.0`](http://www.mhsatman.com/rcaller.php). I would like to load Java-based packages like `XLConnect` but I get the error 'Could not find function "LoadWorkbook"'.

I can not post more of the error here as the Java application that I use was not developed by myself and I only see the error messages. It seems reasonable to me that I can not call R from Java and R calls Java (for XLConnect) again, but do you have any ideas how to make this work? Thanks!